Имя не распознано как имя командлета
Установил python версии 3.11, создал виртуальное  окружение в pycharm и в  консоли вижу это:
py
Windows PowerShell
(C) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation). Все права защищены.
Попробуйте новую кроссплатформенную оболочку PowerShell (https://aka.ms/pscore6)

C:/Users/Алекс/Desktop/Network : Имя "C:/Users/Алекс/Desktop/Network" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильност
ь написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1
+ C:/Users/Алекс/Desktop/Network City Helper BOT/.venv/Scripts/activate ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:/Users/Алекс/Desktop/Network:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


Как это исправить?

У вас путь с пробелами, при запуске такой путь разбивается, и первую часть пути считает командой. Теоретически PyCharm должен понимать, что пути бывают с пробелами (и оборачивать в кавычки), но может что-то не так настроено. Как именно запускаете, после чего эта ошибка возникает?

Ну и проще всего починить переместив проект в папку, путь к которой не содержит пробелов.
